# Does the Gemara talk about interpersonal dynamics between step-siblings in blended families?

Tags: sources-mekorot, family-members, maseches-kesubos

Obviously the model of *get married at age 20, stay married for 70 years, then both spouses drop dead* was not one in the Gemara; if nothing else, enough people died young that remarriages were common. Kesubos, for example, talks about whether a wife has to nurse the babies that her husband had from a previous marriage.

Similarly there's the story of a rabbi who keeps a skull in a special box, and his wife thinks it belongs to his deceased ex and he hasn't gotten over her!

But does the Gemara tell stories of the relations between *siblings* in a blended marriage?  (*Bava Brady*, so to speak?) None are coming to mind at the moment. Though I think in general the Gemara doesn't deal much how kids interact with each other.

Comment: Is this along the lines of what you're looking for? https://www.sefaria.org/Sotah.43b.16?lang=bi Or are you looking for more agaddic stories?

Comment: @JoelK good thanks, but yeah more aggadic -- or at least a halacha based on how they'll treat one another. I changed "relations" to "personal dynamics" in the question accordingly. Thank you!

Comment: Not very detailed, but https://www.sefaria.org/Pesachim.4a.1

Comment: @Heshy And those blended siblings got along well enough that one of them married one of the others, and became Rav's parents.

Comment: There's some in Tanach. The shvatim. Amon and Tamar etc.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct in stating that the Gemara very rarely details the relationships of children at all.
However, here are a few halachos on the topic. 
there is a big sugya regarding yichud in these types of situations (a few of the comments touched upon this) see shulchan aruch even haezer siman 15 seifim 11,22,23 with the classic commentators. also see: [Halacha of Yichud with half sibling](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17298/halacha-of-yichud-with-half-sibling).
The gemara (kesubos 103) a learns from the pasuk detailing kibud av va'aim that one is also chayav to honor a step parent.
The shulchan aruch (Yoreh De'ah 374:4) paskens based on a gemara (Moed Katan 20b) that one sits shiva over the death of a step sibling. If they share a father, the aveilus is d'oraysa but  if they share  mother, then its only m'drabbann.